# Generate exponentialy increase range to make chart look good

Tags: python, charts

I'd like to work out how to generate an increasing set of bar chart steps so that it starts out with very small steps and then increases to a maximum.  I have a histogram of response times that are tightly grouped around the average and then has a long tail to 10 x the average usually.  The chart will have 20 steps, with the first 10 being small and then increasingly increasing until the maximum value.  What pure python formula could achieve this?

Chart small example:  Min = 0, max = 5, average = 0.032

```
0.00 **
0.01 ***
0.02 ****
0.03 *************
0.05 ******
0.08 ****
0.12 ***
0.30 **
1.20 *
2.00 *
3.20 *
5.00 *
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my hacky code to solve my question.  Improvements are welcomed.  It starts at the maximum value and then steps down by a half for each histogram chart bucket until it reaches 3 times the average.  Then the chart buckets are an even fraction of the remaining range of values until zero.

```
    # histogram 0 - max
    bin_size = 20
    bin_values = [0 for _ in range(bin_size+1)]

    bin_max = 150
    average = 0.236

    bin_step = bin_max
    bin_factor = 0.5
    average_step_passed = False
    for x in range(bin_size, 0, -1):
        # print x, bin_step, bin_factor
        bin_values[x] = bin_step
        if not average_step_passed:
            if average * 3 > bin_step:
                bin_values[x] = average * 3
                bin_factor = bin_step / x
                average_step_passed = True
            else:
                bin_step = bin_step * bin_factor
        else:
            bin_values[x] = bin_factor * x

    bin_values[0] = 0
```

This makes a nice histogram as follows (roughly):

```
samples: 69328
average: 0.2607
max: 100.34

Distribution
000.000      0
000.060    696 ***
000.120   7275 *************************************
000.180  26811 **********************************************************
000.240  22364 ***************************************************
000.300   5766 *************************
000.360   2113 ********
000.420   1381 *****
000.480   1149 ***
000.540    513 **
000.600    326 *
000.660    255 *
000.720    245 *
000.820    616 ***
001.570     37
003.140     24
006.270     15
012.540      9
025.080      1
050.170      1
```